# Does an increment always involve a working prototype?

Tags: scrum, development-process, prototyping

I would like to ask a question about Scrum.  At the end of a Sprint, when we have the Sprint Review, we present an *Increment*.

The guide says that this Increment has to be *potentially releasable*.

My question is, does this mean that every increment should involve a running prototype of the software we are building, even involving some mock functionality or data at the beginning?

(I know that it does not have to be fully operational of course.)

**EDIT:** Perhaps my understanding of the word "prototype" is wrong. What I meant by "prototype" was a operational (if not fully functional) piece of software that can be run and be executed.

Comment: I can't help noticing that answers so far mostly seem to be arguing over *what* exactly Scrum prescribes, like arguing over Bible text, rather than examining *why* working increments are (arguably) desirable and what beneficial implications it (arguably) has.

Comment: @Steve well, perhaps because my question is not asking the *why* but the *what*. I am not asking what benefits  does it have either.

Comment: I can't help thinking the "why" would naturally answer your (and other people's) "what", improve the general condition of understanding greatly, and clear up ambiguity or redundancy around phrases like "potentially releasable" (I can't understand how "potentially releasable" differs from "releasable", because the suffix "-able" refers to a potential, and the only sensible interpretation of "releasable" as software professionals understand the word is that it forms something that can be given out to users and which will perform a proper function).

Comment: well, sorry, but I already know the why. But that left me still in the dark. I am interested in the what (which is much more practical) and that is why I asked the question

Comment: I was lucky not to be sipping my tea at the moment I read that, as I would have spat it out. If there was an understanding of the purpose being achieved by the Scrum method, then it would be easy to infer an answer on the question of what condition the software must be in after each sprint. Darkness reigns because it is not clear why the two week sprint is important and what purpose it serves exactly.

Comment: @Steve: what do you mean by that? Are you saying that you don't understand the general purpose of sprints? The purpose is to break down work into manageable chunks with time allocated at the end of each sprint for reflection and improvement.

Comment: @BryanOakley, what do I mean by *what*? I have a general idea about the claims of Scrum, but to be perfectly honest I think the whole thing is basically bunk, and it's practitioners mostly talk bunk.

Comment: @Steve: I apologize for not being more clear. I meant "what do you mean by 'darkness reigns because it is not clear why the two week sprint is important and what purpose it serves exactly". It sounds like you are making claims against scrum without actually knowing what scrum is. Why participate in a question about a methodology you know very little about? Scrum isn't for everyone, but it's a very powerful and effective process for many, many teams.

Answer (score 11):

The wording "*potentially releasable increment*" may indeed appear ambiguous: some people could understand that it MUST be possible to release the product, whereas others understand that it COULD be (in some cases) possible to release (but not always).

Fortunately, the guide gives a very clear [definition](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#artifacts-increment):

> The Increment is the sum of all the Product Backlog items completed
>   during a Sprint and the value of the increments of all previous
>   Sprints. At the end of a Sprint, the new Increment must be "Done,"
>   which means **it must be in useable condition and meet the Scrum
>   Team’s definition of "Done"**. (...) The increment is a step toward a
>   vision or goal. **The increment must be in useable condition
>   regardless of whether the Product Owner decides to release it.**

So there is no ambiguity: every sprint shall deliver a working product that is better than the previous product. It should be of the same quality as a finished product, because the product owner could decide to release it.

It's therefore important not to confuse ***increment*** and ***[prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_prototyping)***: an increment is meant to be releasable, wehereas a prototype is always meant to be a temporary unfinished product.  A prototype is not meant to be releasable at all.

Comment: As I commented to the other answer, perhaps my understanding of the word "prototype" is wrong. I thought "usable condition" meant prototype as opposed to say.. just documentation. So in simple words what should I have at the end of a sprint? A working software system? (even without the full functionality)

Comment: @KansaiRobot a working software system.  Because a documentation is of no value if it would be released. And a documentation is not a usable product.

Comment: Note that it's not uncommon for "prototype" to be misused and applied to what is an increment. For example, if your current sprint goal is achieved but it functionally doesn't make sense yet (e.g. you display stored data, but users cannot cannot input this data yet, maybe because that input feature is the next sprint's goal), that's still an increment since this feature's development (i.e. the displaying of the stored data, the current sprint goal) is finished. Just because the customer doesn't consider that finished doesn't mean that it's not "done" in the scrum team sense.

Comment: @Flater I agree that the boundaries are in some conditions, and especially in the very first sprints somewhat fuzzy.  But it’s a question of mindset: a prototype is something purposely unfinished and therefore of lower quality grade. Prototype featured do not necessarily comply with definition if done. Using this word for increments therefore might mislead and create a mental bias. If people see the product as a prototype, they might let some things not completely done with the intent of later rework and the risk of forgetting it. This is why I recommend not to use it.

Comment: @Christophe: I'm agreeing with you :) I agree with your answer but its phrasing left me worried that since an increment is being defined by its distinction from a prototype, it's important to realize that prototypes get mislabeled as commonly as increments do (since "unfinished" for a customer is not always the same as "unfinished" to a developer). I was just adding an asterisk, not trying to contradict your (IMO) correct answer.

Comment: @Flater I see ! Thanks for pointing it out :-)

Answer (score 4):

An Increment always involves a "Done", potentially releasable, and working product. A prototype doesn't typically meet these characteristics. Instead, incremental improvement of the product is preferred. However, that doesn't mean that you can't use prototyping. Although every Sprint produces incremental improvements to the product, there's nothing that says that you can't also prototype other work in a way that enables you to receive feedback.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. Perhaps we are using different meanings for words. To me a "potentially releasable" product means a prototype. Are those different? Is my understanding of the word prototype wrong?

Comment: @KansaiRobot I'm not sure how you define "prototype", but it's not typically something that is releasable and usable. A prototype is a model that is used to elicit feedback.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how you folks can pull off a releasable product of any significant scope in the first two week sprint.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Maybe you don't succeed. It all depends on how you define "releasable" and "significant scope". I think it's more about demonstrating progress on a rapid basis and making sure your previous work isn't broken by any new work.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, that smells strongly as if the word "releasable" forms part of a *lie* you tell people, especially yourself. Even the idea that each sprint should result in an incremental improvement - in the same way that after two weeks on site, you expect brick walls to be higher and not lower than before - is a fiction, since agile approaches may often result in software being rewrought (and the walls, in effect, being lower than two weeks ago but in a changed configuration that will better support further building than the old higher walls would have).

Comment: @Steve That is wrong, and it doesn't make sense to compare software to a wall. Every iteration does result in incremental improvement. However, it may not necessarily be visible incremental improvement. Perhaps it's tech debt paydown to enable new work in the future. Perhaps it's behind a feature flag and not available for use in production but enabled in demo environments. Perhaps it's an A/B test. To me, potentially releasable means that if you release it, stakeholders won't be in a worse place than they are now. It doesn't mean that they will be in a better place than they are now.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, so basically improvement is whatever you say it is? An improvement is whatever you spend 2 weeks doing? I'm not putting it so provocatively to impugn your tacit skill or understanding, but to emphasise the *vacuity* of communication on the subject. If "potentially releasable" means "the stakeholders have no working software now, and after this release, they still will have no working software so they are no worse off", is that really an honest and felicitous use of the word "releasable"? Robert's point surely is that, for some initial period, there truly is no releasable product.

Comment: @Steve If they don't have working software, you're doing it wrong. They should have working software after every iteration. There may or may not be value in releasing that software if it doesn't meet enough of their needs, but software never regresses from working to non-working. Consider a web application - a "hello world" page with health checks and reuslts from an infrastructure vulnerability scan is working software, but not necessarily valuable enough to release. But maybe that's enough to prove you've established the infrastructure for future work. It can also be demonstrated.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, is there any compiled executable which you would not have the chutzpah to deem "releasable"? Releasable in my view is software of a kind that performs functions *for which it is designed and written* - it has value because it performs those functions, and once released it is used operationally, not as a toy or a curiosity or as a mere proof of work done. I accept an operational application can initially have some but not all of the required screens or functions, but a "hello world" page is not a deliverable or releasable business application by any sensible person's criteria.

Comment: @Steve I don't believe that you understand the purpose of potentially releasable increments. There are differences between something that is "potentially releasable", "releasable", and "worth releasing". Just because something works and is potentially releasable doesn't mean that there's value in releasing it for operational use. However, there's value in demonstrating progression toward something that is worth releasing and the agile methods harness the value of demonstration and the ability to prove that what is desired is feasible.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, with respect, you strain the English language unbearably. Where to start? Does "potentially releasable" mean "maybe releasable, maybe not", expressing uncertainty as to whether it is in a releasable condition (as opposed to the meaning I naturally hear, which is "fully capable of being released, even if it doesn't in fact get released")? If so, then clearly your own argument is that the work is *not necessarily* releasable after each sprint. As for the concept you introduce of a "worthless release", in what sector is worthless software considered "worth demonstrating" or "done"?

Comment: @Steve Potentially releasable means that releasing the software won't put the world in a worse state. Worth releasing depends on your organization's definition of what is useful or valuable to release. In Scrum, every Sprint results in potentially releasable software, meaning it can be released with no ill effects. However, it may not be worth releasing, meaning the cost to release may not outweigh the benefits of releasing. Even without releasing, you can demonstrate work. Consider that "done" for the system is different than "done" for work items, and done work doesn't need to be visible.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, so how does "potentially releasable" differ from "releasable" in your schema? As for a worthless release, is it the case that it is acceptable to have a sprint where the net user-worth of the work done in that sprint is zero, and where the release contains no user-useful function (either relative to the previous release, or at all)? And that demonstrating to users an application without any user-useful function (thus far), has the ability to prove (by magic?) that the user-desired functions are feasible?

Comment: @Steve Something is releasable if it is both potentially releasable and the value exceeds the cost to release. In some cases, a potentially releasable system may have a net user-worth of 0 if the functionality is behind a feature flag and the flag is disabled. Perhaps it will be enabled later, after UAT. Perhaps one feature needs another feature to be valuable, but you get feedback from a pre-production environment on the first feature. The Sprint will always have value because you've demonstrated working functionality and obtained feedback.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, so "potentially releasable" is any work that is not regressive in terms of functionality but also *isn't* "worth releasing", whereas "releasable" is non-regressive work that is actually "worth releasing"? But the former category does not in fact exist, because a Sprint "always has value", because it "demonstrates working functionality and obtains feedback" (including about worthless functionality, or features hidden by a flag?)? And initially, since you cannot regress from zero, basically any work is always releasable too, even if it contains zero progress for user-functionality?

Comment: I think my problem is that, besides the fact that contradictions seem to emerge as soon as any weight is placed (that is, as soon as the words stop being used in a meaningless sense), the words appear to be chosen to confuse rather than clarify. If a "potential release" is a "worthless release" and a "release" is a "worthwhile release", why not describe them as such? I assume you think "I don't want 2 weeks of my work described as worthless", but it is worthless (of no operational value) to users, and it's only your Scrum method that set the user up as king to begin with.

Comment: A more straightforward description of reality in my view, is that regardless of method followed, the initial work in most projects of substance is not "done" (except according to a schedule of minor tasks whose content, value, and criteria for completion are determined entirely by the developer, not assessable by users). The initial work has no operational value (any value that isn't contingent on further work being executed and the attendant risk of failure). Like a foetus in the womb, it is not releasable, workable, or proven to be feasible, and definitely not "done".